# How to tell which (java) build system eclipse uses?

Tags: eclipse, build

When working with software projects that employ the Java programming language, there are 3 commonly employed *build systems*:

- Apache ANT-IVY,
- Apache Maven,
- and Gradle.

Looking through the jungle of the Eclipse Interface each of those build buzzwords occur, yet this IDE gives me no clue what build system it actually uses?

How can I find out what Eclipse thinks should happen when I tell it to build the project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't set up any special then none of these system is used to build a Java project. The Eclipse Java compiler runs automatically as you type. Other builders written as Eclipse plugins run when resources change, you can see information about these in the 'Builders' page of the project Properties.

There are Eclipse plugins that add support for all the build systems you mention. They are used if you create a project specifying which system you want to use.

Comment: your answer confirms what I was somewhat trial-and-erroringly figured out myself. I take it the info I look at is found in the Projects properties -> builders tab.